# Accessing libraries from other software's python module

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python so please excuse me if I happen to confuse some terminology or procedures.

I'm trying to write some automation code for a data analysis software I use (Agisoft Metashape). This software has a python API with an included library to use it's functions (so in the code I just use `import Metashape` and when the code is executed within the software everything works).

The problem is that I try to use some external libraries for the processing such as `pandas` which seems to not be accessible from Metashape, meaning when I execute my code using Metashape, I get an error saying `No module named 'pandas'`.

Outside metashape I am able to use them because I write and test my code using Anaconda (which in turn does not have Metashape's libraries).

How can I "install" pandas libraries into the software itself? It seems like it has a python console...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the python application in this Metashape-Tool having its own python distribution/interpreter or does it use your system/anaconda one?

Comment: @FloWil It has it's own. That's probably why it can't access the libraries Anaconda has.

Comment: This link can help you: https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=3412.0

Comment: I had a similar situation once where I had to interact between IronPython and a regular CPython installation. I don't think there is an easy solution for this. My suggestion would be to structure your workflow in such a way that you export your data from Metashape with minimal code and dependencies, then do the heavy lifting in Pandas/Anaconda outside of the custom python installation. Anything else may become a nightmare to maintain once any package or application part updates in an incompatible way. 
Calling the external python script with `subprocess` did the trick for me back then

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @MaryamBahrami your link definitlry helped but unfortunatly when I try to run `python -m pip install pandas` using the python.exe file located inside Agisoft's library, I get a syntax error. Tried to look around and navigating to pip's scripts folder did not help.
@FloWil I'm trying to automate the data generation workflow so I can work elsewhere. This is nessecary in order to get data to work on with NumPy or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time dealing with this issue, the easiest way to solve this is by installing the Metashape module by itself to the DE you're working on (say, PyCharm).
Just use the instructions in this link:

https://agisoft.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/31000148930-how-to-install-metashape-stand-alone-python-module

Note: we had some trouble executing our code in an offline docker container, so I asked about this (and answered myself) too:

https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=13618.0